# Using function max cakephp in query

Tags: cakephp, sql-function

Hello everyone como estan will see I have this query in SQL

```
SELECT MAX(id_alternativa) FROM pregunta_alternativa WHERE id_pregunta = 7
```

which I'm doing in cakephp using the MAX function framework

```
public function register() {
$query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find()
        ->select([
            'id_alternativa' => $query->func()->max(['id_alternativa'])
        ])->where(['id_pregunta' => '7']);

$this->set('alternatives',$query);  }
```

but it shows this is the message Error

**Error: Call to a member function func() on null File C:\xampp\htdocs\serapp\src\Controller\PreguntasAlternativasController.php Line: 14**

as I see documentation so their functions are used

[Sql Functions Cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was simple place it here, referring to the documentation

```
 public function register() {
    $query = $this->PreguntasAlternativas->find();
    $query->select(['id_alternativa' => $query->func()->max('id_alternativa')
            ])->where(['id_pregunta' => '7']);
```

You must be setear variable $query